# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Tags: magento-1.9, php, memory

Got a php error, Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted.
It is quite strange, because I created a php info file to check the settings.

The setting of the server is memory_limit 12288M (server got enough free RAM).

What am I missing? Is there a other setting that is set to the 512MB?

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 53248 bytes) in /lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 74
```

Comment: Have you also checked .htaccess `php_value memory_limit`?

Comment: @sv3n Yes, the main (root) .htaccess file contains the line `php_value memory_limit 12288M` so that can also not be the problem..

Comment: What code execution is happening when you get this error? It has only happened to me when i have set up something like a collection in a loop or the like.

Comment: First it is not memory issue. Some of your collection loading or looping or collecting data take more time. first check log which collection take time.

Comment: @RamaChandran Thanks for your reply. What log exactly do I need to check? Where will this be logged?

Comment: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted before what collection run check in php error log

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

You can put also in index.php/cron.php ini_set('memory_limit', '768M'); or more.

Comment: Thanks! But it is for Magento 1.9.3 so php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production does not work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can do the same with index.php and cron.php.